# Having y-axis in log scale base 2 using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have made a chart using `pgfplots` as written below and I want to have the y-axis in logarithmic scale. This code works fine but the base of the logarithm is 10. How can I change it to base 2?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=0.5\textwidth,
        width=\textwidth,
        xlabel=LabelX,
        xtick={1,...,10},
        ylabel=LabelY,
        ymode=log,
    ]
        \addplot[mark=*,blue] table[x=V,y=R] {data1.data};
        \addplot[mark=x,red] table[x=V,y=E] {data2.data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the `log basis x={<number>}` and/or `log basis y={<number>}` options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=0.5\textwidth,
        width=\textwidth,
        xlabel=LabelX,
        xtick={1,...,10},
        ylabel=LabelY,
        ymode=log,
       log basis y={2}
]
        \addplot[mark=*,blue] coordinates {(2,2) (5,8) (7,16)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to keep the nice "inbetween" log ticks for the logarithmic axis when doing this?