# Base 2 logarithmic scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am plotting data with `pgfplots` using `semilogxaxis` that use base 10 logarithm.  Is there a way to change the base of logarithmic-axes (I need an axis where power of 2 values are separated by the same amount of pixels) ?

Comment: Related: [Having y-axis in log scale base 2 using pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132703/having-y-axis-in-log-scale-base-2-using-pgfplots)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, but I wasn't able to find this question. I voted to close my own question as duplicate.